# Get total number of events on each current day

Tags: mysql, range, unix-timestamp

How can you get the number of current events that are enlisted on a current day with a UNIX timestamp, for example, there are 2 events on 17th February 2012 and 1 event on 19th February 2012. It should return rows like this:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
           [event_id] => 4
           [total_events] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
           [event_id] => 18
           [total_events] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
           [event_id] => 19
           [total_events] => 1
        )
)
```

The first two items are scheduled on the same day of each other (17th Feb) and the last item is on the 19th of Feb with no other events scheduled the same day.

I tried this method, but it returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 1
            [total_events] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 2
            [total_events] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [event_id] => 3
            [total_events] => 1
        )

)
```

This is the following SQL I've done so far, without a good result:

```
SELECT events.event_id,
       SUM(IF(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(events.event_starts), '%y %m %d') = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(events.event_ends), '%y %m %d'), 1, 0)) AS total_events

FROM
(
    scheduled_events events
)
WHERE ( events.event_starts >= 1328486400 AND events.event_ends <= 1329695940 )
GROUP BY events.event_id
```

The two UNIX timestamps are ranging from Monday 13th Feb 12:00AM to Sunday 19th Feb 11:59PM as in of the following week scheme.

How do I retrieve the number of events that returns the number of events on each day of the week when there is an event on that day of a following event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. It should return each event_id within the two timestamps and a COUNT of all other event_ids that start on the same day

```
SELECT e1.event_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT e2.event_id)
FROM   scheduled_events AS e1
   INNER JOIN scheduled_events AS e2
       ON  e1.event_id!=e2.event_id 
           AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(e1.event_starts))=DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(e2.event_starts))
WHERE ( e1.event_starts >= 1328486400 AND e1.event_ends <= 1329695940 )
GROUP BY e1.event_id
```